# Differentiating a representation $p(x)\mapsto p(A^{-1}x)\det(A)^{\alpha}$ to get representation of Lie Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

**Hello**, I am studying algebraic groups and I am stuck on a problem which is subdivided into $4$ parts. I am stuck on the second part of the problem. I will introduce you to the problem by showing what I have done so far, but if you want you to move ahead to my real issue, you can do so, I will make sure it will be easy to notice where my problems begin by (really) highlighting it. :)

---

**Problem:**

*Setup:* Let $P_n$ be the complex vector space of homogeneous polynomials in two variables $x_1$, $x_2$, and consider the representation $V_{n,\alpha}$, $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}$ of $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ given in the following way. Let $A\in GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ and $p\in P_n$, and define the action of $A$ by $p(x)\mapsto p(A^{-1}x)\det(A)^{\alpha}$, where $x=(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{C}^2$.

In the first part I was asked to prove this is a representation and I was also asked to study the action of the center of $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ and $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$.

Now, in the second part, I am asked to differentiate the representation and study how the elements in the Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}l_2$ and $\mathfrak{s}l_2$ act. (actually the second part was a bit longer, but I am only interested in this part at the moment). :)

---

**Solution:**

*First part*: To prove it is a representation, I just have to check the definition of a representation that the conditions hold. Elements of the center of $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ are of the form $aI$ where $I\in GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ is the identity and $a\not = 0\in\mathbb{C}$. Letting $A=aI$ we get
$$p(x)\mapsto p((aI)^{-1}x)\det(aI)^{\alpha}=a^{-n}p(x)a^{2\alpha}=a^{2\alpha-n}p(x),$$
where I have used that the polynomial is homogeneous to get $a^{-n}$. The study of elements of $Z(SL_2(\mathbb{C}))$ has similar computation.

$\text{}$

*Second part*: To understand the derivative (or do you say to understand the representation?) we "**only**" have to compute the derivative for the basis elements of $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ and $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$. The basis elements of $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ are
$$X=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix},\quad Y=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix},\quad Z=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix},\quad W=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Computing the differential using the first basis matrix means we want to compute the limit
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{p(e^{-tX}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix})-p(\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix})}{t}.$$
Since $X$ is nilpotent, $e^{-tX}$ is easy to compute. Namely, 
$$e^{-tx}=I+-tX=\begin{bmatrix}1 & -t \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$$
Applying this to the vector gives us
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -t \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x-ty \\ y\end{bmatrix}.$$
Hence, the derivative is given by
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{p(x-ty,y)-p(x,y)}{t}=\dfrac{-yt{p_x}'(x,y)}{t}=-y{p_x}'(x,y).$$
Similarly, for $Y$, we have
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{p(x,y-tx)-p(x,y)}{t}=\dfrac{-xt{p_y}'(x,y)}{t}=-x{p_y}'(x,y).$$

$\text{}$

**HERE DOES MY REAL PROBLEMS BEGIN:**

Since $e^D$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix, is just the matrix where you take the exponential of the diagonal entries we have that
$$e^{-tZ}=\begin{bmatrix}e^{-t} & 0 \\ 0 & e^t\end{bmatrix}.$$
In this case the derivative becomes
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{p(e^{-t}x,e^{t}y)-p(x,y)}{t},$$
which I honestly don't know what to do with. The same for $W$, which becomes
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{p(e^{t}x,e^{t}y)-p(x,y)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{e^{nt}p(x,y)-p(x,y)}{t},$$
which I really don't know what to do with either.

When you have computed all these limits I guess you just multiply all limits by $\det(A)^{\alpha}$?

---

**Questions:**

1. How do I compute the last two limits?
2. Why do we only have to compute the derivative for the basis elements?
3. I don't know how to interpret 'study how the elements in the Lie algebras act'. What is meant by that?

Much of this theory is really new to me, so there are a lot for me to get my head around.

I guess my second question should be trivial, but I cannot really answer that question. Perhaps I would arrive at an answer by managing to compute the limits and answer question 3?

What I mean by question $3$, is if it is only to plug in different matrices of $\mathfrak{g}l_2$ and $\mathfrak{s}l_2$ in the derivatives I have computed? But that does not sound right to me.

I would be happy for any help. Thanks!

Comment: What source are you learning from? Because in the context of algebraic groups, that is not how to find a derivative. It looks like you might really be working with a Lie group perhaps.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, good point. :) I am using; "Representation Theory: A First Course" - Fulton-Harris, "Lie groups Beyond an Introduction" - Knapp, then a few articles on Reductive algebraic groups. The more I think about it, I think your statement is correct. That is, I am working with a Lie group. I went to my professors office a few days ago and asked about the derivative. Then he explained that definition of the derivative and showed me how to compute it for one of the basis elements. So yeah, we are also going through a lot of Lie groups and Lie algebras.

Comment: I should probably head to his office today and ask for some more help and explanation! :)